# rust: improve number iterations and conversions into superscript

Tags: rust, type-conversion, superscript

Currently, that's the way I'm doing it.

```rust
fn main() {
    let superscript_digits = ["⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹"];
    let sample_num = 1234;

    for i in sample_num.to_string().chars() {
        print!("{}", superscript_digits[i.to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize])
    }
    println!();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fbfbbd197b11f95c8342a50c8524983d)

This gets it done with a fairly minimal amount of code. But I worry that it's not an optimal solution and the conversions are a performance impairment.

In the final implementation the incoming numbers are floats, so even more conversion is happening. I would just need the rounded numbers and do something like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let superscript_digits = ["⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹"];
    let sample_nums: Vec<f64> = [12.7, 27.4, 32.8, 41.2].to_vec();

    for num in sample_nums {
        for c in num.round().to_string().chars() {
            print!("{}", superscript_digits[c.to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize])
        }
        println!();
    }
}
```

I hoped that someone with more experience than myself could share a better way of doing it and why it is so.

Comment: Wouldn't a hash map be suitable for mapping digits in terms of access speed.

Comment: An `array` is the fastest access you will get. If you want you can write it down into a `match` statement. but i suppose the performance is equal. the array is a constant, you can define it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since benchmarking `println!()` was not very relevant in my opinion, I decided to use [criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) on two variants returning a `String` (see `superscript_v1_collect()` and `superscript_v2_collect()` below).
The `v1` version is near to the original code; the `v2` version tries to get rid of intermediate storage and conversions.
The result was disappointing (see `my_benchmark.rs` below) because the performances were not so different and were varying a lot.

I guess this is due to the memory allocation in the returned `String`, so I decided to produce two other variants, much less convenient but avoiding many dynamic allocations (see `superscript_v1_ref_mut()` and `superscript_v2_ref_mut()` below).
This time, the results are much more stable (especially for `v2`) and show a substantial improvement in `v2` over `v1`.

Note that in `v2` I chose a kind of hardcoded solution in which I know the maximal number of digits (10 for `u32`).

`src/lib.rs`

```rust
pub fn superscript_v1_collect(value: u32) -> String {
    const SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS: [&str; 10] =
        ["⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹"];
    value
        .to_string()
        .chars()
        .map(|c| SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS[c.to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize])
        .collect()
}

pub fn superscript_v2_collect(mut value: u32) -> String {
    const SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS: [char; 10] =
        ['⁰', '¹', '²', '³', '⁴', '⁵', '⁶', '⁷', '⁸', '⁹'];
    let mut started = false;
    let mut power_of_ten = 1_000_000_000;
    if value == 0 {
        '⁰'.to_string()
    } else {
        (0..10)
            .filter_map(|_| {
                let digit = value / power_of_ten;
                value -= digit * power_of_ten;
                power_of_ten /= 10;
                if digit != 0 || started {
                    started = true;
                    Some(SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS[digit as usize])
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
            .collect()
    }
}

pub fn superscript_v1_ref_mut(
    value: u32,
    result: &mut String,
) {
    const SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS: [&str; 10] =
        ["⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹"];
    result.clear();
    for c in value.to_string().chars() {
        result.push_str(SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS[c.to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize]);
    }
}

pub fn superscript_v2_ref_mut(
    mut value: u32,
    result: &mut String,
) {
    const SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS: [char; 10] =
        ['⁰', '¹', '²', '³', '⁴', '⁵', '⁶', '⁷', '⁸', '⁹'];
    result.clear();
    let mut started = false;
    let mut power_of_ten = 1_000_000_000;
    if value == 0 {
        result.push('⁰')
    } else {
        for _ in 0..10 {
            let digit = value / power_of_ten;
            value -= digit * power_of_ten;
            power_of_ten /= 10;
            if digit != 0 || started {
                started = true;
                result.push(SUPERSCRIPT_DIGITS[digit as usize]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use prog::{
    superscript_v1_collect, superscript_v1_ref_mut, superscript_v2_collect,
    superscript_v2_ref_mut,
};

fn main() {
    let sample_nums = [
        0,
        12,
        345,
        6_789,
        12_345,
        678_912,
        3_456_789,
        12_345_678,
        912_345_678,
    ];
    let mut s1 = String::new();
    let mut s2 = String::new();
    for num in sample_nums.iter() {
        superscript_v1_ref_mut(*num, &mut s1);
        superscript_v2_ref_mut(*num, &mut s2);
        println!(
            "{}  {}  {}  {}  {}",
            *num,
            superscript_v1_collect(*num),
            superscript_v2_collect(*num),
            s1,
            s2
        );
    }
}
/*
0  ⁰  ⁰  ⁰  ⁰
12  ¹²  ¹²  ¹²  ¹²
345  ³⁴⁵  ³⁴⁵  ³⁴⁵  ³⁴⁵
6789  ⁶⁷⁸⁹  ⁶⁷⁸⁹  ⁶⁷⁸⁹  ⁶⁷⁸⁹
12345  ¹²³⁴⁵  ¹²³⁴⁵  ¹²³⁴⁵  ¹²³⁴⁵
678912  ⁶⁷⁸⁹¹²  ⁶⁷⁸⁹¹²  ⁶⁷⁸⁹¹²  ⁶⁷⁸⁹¹²
3456789  ³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹  ³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹  ³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹  ³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹
12345678  ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸  ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸  ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸  ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸
912345678  ⁹¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸  ⁹¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸  ⁹¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸  ⁹¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸
*/
```

`benches/my_benchmark.rs`

```rust
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};

use prog::{
    superscript_v1_collect, superscript_v1_ref_mut, superscript_v2_collect,
    superscript_v2_ref_mut,
};

fn benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut c = c.benchmark_group("benches");
    let sample_nums = [
        0,
        12,
        345,
        6_789,
        12_345,
        678_912,
        3_456_789,
        12_345_678,
        912_345_678,
    ];
    let mut s1 = String::new();
    let mut s2 = String::new();
    c.bench_function("superscript_v1_collect", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            for num in sample_nums.iter() {
                black_box(superscript_v1_collect(black_box(*num)));
            }
        })
    });
    c.bench_function("superscript_v2_collect", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            for num in sample_nums.iter() {
                black_box(superscript_v2_collect(black_box(*num)));
            }
        })
    });
    c.bench_function("superscript_v1_ref_mut", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            for num in sample_nums.iter() {
                superscript_v1_ref_mut(black_box(*num), black_box(&mut s1));
            }
        })
    });
    c.bench_function("superscript_v2_ref_mut", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            for num in sample_nums.iter() {
                superscript_v2_ref_mut(black_box(*num), black_box(&mut s2));
            }
        })
    });
}

criterion_group!(benches, benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
/*
superscript_v1_collect ... [578.36 ns 580.18 ns 583.00 ns]
superscript_v2_collect ... [571.34 ns 572.70 ns 574.11 ns]
superscript_v1_ref_mut ... [321.37 ns 321.79 ns 322.27 ns]
superscript_v2_ref_mut ... [271.51 ns 272.00 ns 272.59 ns]
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only using numeric data, you're correct in that you shouldn't need to cast to strings to get a value out of it. You can use the modulo operator to get the last digit in a loop, then use integer division to truncate that from the value before the next iteration.

Here are the benchmarks I wrote to show a couple of different implementations, including the modulo one which should be the fastest.

```rust
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;
use test::Bencher;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[bench]
fn original(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let superscript_digits = ["⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹"];
    let sample_num = 1234;

    b.iter(|| {
        for i in sample_num.to_string().chars() {
            print!("{}", superscript_digits[i.to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize])
        }
        println!();
    });
}

#[bench]
fn numeric(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let superscript_digits = ["⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹"];
    let sample_num = 1234;

    b.iter(|| {
        let mut sample_num = sample_num;
        while sample_num > 0 {
            print!("{}", superscript_digits[sample_num % 10]);
            sample_num /= 10;
        }
        println!();
    });
}

#[bench]
fn hashmap(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let superscript_digits = HashMap::<char, &str>::from_iter([
        ('0', "⁰"),
        ('1', "¹"),
        ('2', "²"),
        ('3', "³"),
        ('4', "⁴"),
        ('5', "⁵"),
        ('6', "⁶"),
        ('7', "⁷"),
        ('8', "⁸"),
        ('9', "⁹"),
    ]);
    let sample_num = 1234;

    b.iter(|| {
        for i in sample_num.to_string().chars() {
            print!("{}", superscript_digits[&i])
        }
        println!();
    });
}
```

results from `cargo bench`:

```
running 3 tests
test tests::original       ... bench:         130 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test tests::numeric        ... bench:         111 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test tests::hashmap        ... bench:         169 ns/iter (+/- 2)
```

However, these are on the order of `ns`, so it is unlikely you'll notice any difference unless you are a very performance-critical domain.

Comment: *"In the final implementation the incoming numbers are floats"* - I feel the numeric approach wouldn't be very helpful for floats, though I like this answer because it shows the original is plenty fast anyway.

Comment: What are the benchmark with : 1) `AHashMap ` in `ahash` crate. 2) `Vec::get_unchecked()`. 3) `FxHashMap` in `fxhash` crate?

Comment: @xcwang any map structure will always be slower than array indexing, and `get_unchecked` might save *a couple clock cycles*, but I'm not sure how `checked_add` works at that low level, and it doesn't add any runtime to the program.

Comment: Isn't `println!()` the slowest operation in the benchmarks? And the `numeric()` enumerates the digits in reverse order; what would be the cost of reordering? (I guess you need a storage, and iterate backwards over it)

Comment: @prog-fh I think you need to do *something* with a value in a bench to keep it from being optimized out, and you can't return so is there something better than printing? don't know about how aggressive the compiler is or the best practices around that. and just plain forgot the order in the mod one -_- the time spent for any string reversal blows up the run time, so I prefer your answer.